# The link "inspect" is not available for devices on Chrome DevTools

Tags: android, google-chrome-devtools, adb

DevTools displays the devices list, but there is no links "inspect" for them.
USB debugging is enabled in settings. The devices were restarted. adb server was restarted as well. The issue is observed for a real device and for an emulator on Android Studio also.

[image: Screenshot from DevTools]

Comment: Is there a Chrome for Android instance running on the phone that Chrome can connect to for remote debugging?

Comment: I run it. So now I see only Google Chrome on the list and nothing else. I just would like to inspect another app. How can I enable inspection for another app?

Comment: That needs to be enabled in the app where the WebView is embedded in: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/remote-debugging/webviews